# Getting Sass to parse browser hacks

Tags: css, sass

What's the best approach to getting Sass (3.4.15) to parse browser CSS property hacks - not using compass or any other library. E.g. `'_property'` or `'*property'`.

```
.hack-test{
    display: inline-block;
    display: *inline;
}

Invalid CSS after " display: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "*inline;"
```

I searched around Stack Overflow but could not find anything that could definitively answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sass strings, in such a way that the invalid css is injected as a string.
I put it all inside a mixin for re-use:

```
$star: "*inline";

@mixin hack-test($selector) {
  #{$selector} {
    display: inline-block;
    display: #{$star};
  }
}
```

So if you try and use the mixin:

```
@include hack-test('.foo');
```

The css output will be as desired:

```
.foo {
  display: inline-block;
  display: *inline;
}
```

You can view some SCSS browser hacks I've put on Github [here](https://github.com/asafusan/SCSS-specific-browser-hacks)

Comment: I see what you did there! I'm still getting an error though: `Error: Invalid CSS after "...lude hack-test(": expected ")", was ".foo);"`

Comment: I forgot the $star variable. Where do you get the error? While trying to compile the SCSS?

Comment: While trying to compile, yes. I'm still getting the error. Would the version of Ruby installed affect anything?

Comment: I see the issue, the parameter should be in quotes: `@include hack-test('.foo');`

Comment: fixed my answer following @PaulRedmond comment. Is working now